# How to use local sourcemaps instead of uploaded ones in sentry

Tags: javascript, sentry, source-maps

Sentry's documentation explains how to upload sourcemaps to sentry by using the sentry-cli.
But in my case I do not want to upload those to sentry,
instead all my sourcemaps are stored right next to original files so eg. if the js is in

```
https://example.com/assets/vendor-1234.js
```

then sourcemaps are in

```
https://example.com/assets/vendor-1234.js.map
```

and the source file contains this as its last line:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=vendor-1234.js.map
```

But for some reason sentry is unable to parse sourcemaps and shows me unusable stack trace:

```
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js in Object.c at line 1:81411 In App
/main.db19209bcb379dbd.js in e.sendError at line 1:49765 In App
/main.db19209bcb379dbd.js at line 1:47450 In App
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js in V.emit at line 1:1078207 In App
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js at line 1:1102834 In App
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js in V.emit at line 1:1078207 In App
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js in K.handleCloseEvent at line 1:1087048 In App
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js in closed at line 1:1086743 In App
/vendor.28c4913e04ca07b6.js in V.emit at line 1:1078207 In App
```

All files are accessible from the internet without any authentication.

Is there something I can do so sentry will use the local sourcemaps instead of requiring me to upload them using sentry-cli?

Answer (score 0):

A plethora of things could be going wrong. In general, your setup looks good. I recommend doing the following:

- Check the size of your source files and source maps. There is an upper limit as to how big they can be. I believe it is around 5 MB.
- Check your project settings and make sure you have the "Enable JavaScript source fetching" option enabled.

Bonus tip : You can ask anybody at Sentry to enable the "Source Map Debugger" beta feature for your org by providing your organization identifier and you might get a feature that will explain what the issue was.